# Как перебрать слова из строки (разделены пробелами) и занести в вектор (без цикла do-while) С++?

Tags: c++, vector, for

Пытаюсь выполнить задание в Яндекс. Практикуме по С++. Надо перебрать слова из сроки ввода (getline). И тут у меня ступор. С помощью do-while я сделал, но техподдержка настаивает на альтернативном решении.

Натолкните на мысль, пожалуйста.

Думал, перебрать посимвольно через char for-циклом, но не могу сообразить, как отследить начало и конец слов.

Comment: Видимо, они хотят, чтобы вы использовали всякие стандартные алгоритмы и итераторы - типа std::copy в итератор. Ну не знаю, я бы показал, что внутри у std::copy лежит while тому умнику, кто это задание придумал.

Comment: Еще вариант с помощью рекурсии раз уж циклы запрещены.

Comment: Подсказка раз: `std::istringstream`, подсказка два: `std::istream_iterator`. А дальше сами...

Answer (score 1):

В общем, решение следующее:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;


int main() {
    /* FOR SUPPORT: объявляем переменную для хранения строки вводимой пользователем */
    string query;
    /* FOR SUPPORT: считываем строку целиком */
    getline(cin, query);


    /* FOR SUPPORT: объявляем вектор строк для хранения слов */
    vector<string> words;
    /* FOR SUPPORT: объявляем строку для хранения слова */
    string word;
    /* FOR SUPPORT: начинаем цикл от 0 до размера строки (проходим посимвольно по всей строке) */
    for (int i = 0; i < query.size(); ++i) {
        /* FOR SUPPORT: условие на выполнение блока:
         * символ это пробел */
        if (query[i] == ' ') {
            /* FOR SUPPORT: добавляем слово в конец вектора слов */
            words.push_back(word);
            /* FOR SUPPORT: присваиваем переменной пустую строку, т.е. начинаем новое слово */
            word = ""s;
        /* FOR SUPPORT: условие на выполнение блока (когда все условия выше - не верны):
         * символ это не пробел (обратное условие) */
        } else {
            /* FOR SUPPORT: добавляем символ к строке.
             * Этим блоком мы собираем слово в переменной word */
            word += query[i];
        }
    }
    /* FOR SUPPORT: добавляем последнее слово word в конец вектора words */
    words.push_back(word);


    /* FOR SUPPORT: проходим по всем словам из вектора слов */
    for (string word : words) {
        /* FOR SUPPORT: выводим слово между [ и ] */
        cout << '[' << word << ']' << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно обрабатывать входной поток по словам, то [for_each](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) нужно применить к [istream_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator):

```
// g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror read-words-1.cpp

#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

void print(const std::string &s) {
    std::cout << '\"' << s << "\"\n";
}

int main() {
    std::for_each(
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin),
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
        print
    );
}
```

> ```
> $ g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror read-words-1.cpp 
> $ echo -e "aa bb cc\ndd ee ff" | ./a.out 
> "aa"
> "bb"
> "cc"
> "dd"
> "ee"
> "ff"
> ```

Если вы собираетесь разбирать строку на слова, то [istream_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) надевает на строку поток чтения:

```
// g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror read-words-2.cpp

#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

void print(const std::string &s) {
    std::cout << '\"' << s << "\"\n";
}

int main() {
    const std::string s = "aa bb cc";
    std::istringstream iss(s);
    std::for_each(
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss),
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
        print
    );
}
```

> ```
> $ g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror read-words-2.cpp 
> $ ./a.out 
> "aa"
> "bb"
> "cc"
> ```